# default open by pdf viewer registry edit windows 7

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry

I am facing a problem in my friend's pc.All shortcuts pointing to an exe opens in adobe acrobat and output the error "This file format is not supported".This is the same when any exe(program exe or setup exe) is launched.I doubt the problem is in the registry that has become corrupt and is opening all executable files with adobe pdf.I cannot even run regedit to edit the entries as even that opens with adobe pdf with the error.Please guide how can the problem be solved through some script.The OS is windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: This is not a really programming question. You should try some easier solutions before (CCleaner, Windows Repair...)

Answer (score 1):

You could to create .txt file from desctop. Then write:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]
@="exefile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```

Then save as blabla.reg and run it. Click "OK". I think, it's all :)

Comment: unfortunately I cannot create a .txt file as notepad is an exe file so I created this reg file in my pc and tried to run it on my friend's pc.Again the same problem regedit is also an exe so the reg file cannot be imported even by double clicking it.

Comment: Can you run ".COM" files ? Try COMMAND.COM in the run/search box then see if it can run regedit or REG.EXE

Comment: no executable files can be run.no .com, .exe, .bat, .vbs, .msi, .cmd nothing.The problem got solved by creating a new profile. @Morbo